# Error viewing Joomla system info

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator

I am getting an error while trying to view the system info of my Joomla site. I am on Joomla 3.4.5.The error is as shown

> Fatal error: Class 'JPlatform' not found in /public_html/mywebsite/administrator/components/com_admin/models/sysinfo.php on line 138.

What could be the cause of this error? Any help to resolve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, there has been an issue somewhere in your upgrades. I'd simply suggest:

1. [Downloading a fresh copy of Joomla 3.x](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.4.5/Joomla_3.4.5-Stable-Full_Package.zip)
2. Extract `administrator/components/com_admin`
3. Zip it up
4. Upload it to your server

Comment: I did just that but no success. I even uploaded joomla 3.4.4 to 3.4.5 update but it's not working at all

Comment: Could you try installing the full 3.4.5 update package (9mb) via your Extension Manager please: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.4.5/Joomla_3.4.5-Stable-Update_Package.zip

Comment: This finally worked and the site is working well. I appreciate bro